# Twitter Followers in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, sdk

How to make twitter followers list in iPhone sdk I m using ***MGTwitterEngine*** and when I try the following method:

```
[_engine getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:NO];
```

I m not getting followers list

Answer (score 1):

USE like `[_engine getFollowersIncludingCurrentStatus:YES];`

And Call SOAuthEngine method to get list on console

```
- (void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier {

    NSLog(@"User Info Received: %@", userInfo);

    followers = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    for (NSDictionary *u in userInfo ) {
        Tweet *tweet = [[Tweet alloc]initWithTweetDictionary:u];
        [followers addObject:tweet];

        [tweet release];

    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Tweet is model class which has Dictionary and method like

```
- (NSString *)tweet {
    return [tweets objectForKey:@"text"];

}
```